# "if" statement isn't confirming object as not-null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swiper.js

I have the below code (simplified).

```
const SwiperComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const [swiper, setSwiper] = useState(null);

    const slideTo = (index: any) => {
        if (swiper) {
            swiper.slideTo(index);
        }

    return (<Swiper onSwiper={setSwiper} />)
}
```

Typescript is saying the `swiper` object in `swiper.slideTo(index)` could be null.

```
TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
```

Isn't my `if` statement doing a not-null check? Why is TS saying it could be null when it can't be.

UPDATE:
I just now see Typescript is giving me a second error on the `onSwiper=` part of the component.

```
TS2322: Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<null>>' is not assignable to type '(swiper: Swiper) => void'.   Types of parameters 'value' and 'swiper' are incompatible.     Type 'Swiper' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<null>'.       Type 'Swiper' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: null): null'.
```

I think this error is related to above maybe. I'm having trouble parsing what this error is really saying though.

Comment: You have the set the initial value of `swiper` to `null` in the `useState` call. If you're not modifying swiper elsewhere it will be null. Null check will be useless in that case.

Comment: I'm surprised you're getting this error. It should be `Property 'slideTo' does not exist on type 'never'.` if you do not call `setSwiper()` elsewhere. Ist this the complete code?

Comment: It's not the complete code. `setSwiper` is passed to a callback function within the swiper component, `<Swiper onSwiper={setSwiper}>`. As i understand it, this simply calls the passed function with the swiper instance as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I changed `useState(null)` to `useState<any>(null)`.